# Using XML with REST API through Azure Datafactory V2

Tags: json, xml, rest, azure-data-factory, twinfield

I need to connect with a webservice through a REST API, get data and insert that data in a Azure SQL Database.
We are using Apache Airflow for that but our engineer is leaving. Finding a replacement has proven to be very hard. Programming skills (Python) are required to work with Apache Airflow.

That is why I am investigating if we use can Datafactory since it requires less programming skills.
However, it seems that the REST connector only understands JSON, while our source is delivering XML.

What would be a possible solution getting XML from a REST API using datafactory? That requires little to no programming skills?

Comment: It's possible to use the Web activity to call a REST API which returns XML, however if the API has many pages, calling it in a For Each activity will be extremely expensive and a bad pattern.  Look for alternatives like a notebook or third-party tool as per the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the documentation, Data Factory Rest connector will only consume JSON from rest services.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest
Have you tried to alter the Accept header in your request to application/json
Basically this request the response to be in JSON and not XML.

Regards Frode.

Comment: The source does not offer JSON at all….  Using ADFv2 IS + the Zapsys SSIS Powerpack I am able to use ADF to consume xml