# Still not working: Using XML with REST API through Azure Datafactory V2?

Tags: azure-data-factory

This post [Using XML with REST API through Azure Datafactory V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964612/using-xml-with-rest-api-through-azure-datafactory-v2) says ADF does not support REST API with XML but since the post is 2 years old, I was wondering if Microsoft has enable this feature now?

**EDIT**

Currently I am doing like this where I am adding an addtional headers where I define it should be XML. However, the format still looks json when I preview the data.
[image]

Comment: You want to store the response returned from the REST API as an XML file? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Yes that is correct. I have updated my post, hopefully it becomes more clear what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get this warning message while giving `Accept` header in copy activity saying `application/json` value will be automatically give as the value for this header.

[image]

- Therefore, in copy data activity, the accepted API format is `JSON` only. As an alternate, you can use web activity and copy data to get the required response in the following way.
- I used a sample API which returns XML response. I used this in the web activity and the debug output would be as follows:

[image]

- The entire XML response is stored as a string. Now I have taken a copy data activity where the source is a CSV file (contents of this file don't matter. Try to take a file similar to below file).

[image]

- Now, create an additional column for this source with any column name and value as shown below:

```
@activity('Web1').output.Response
```

[image]

- Now, choose `delimited text` as the sink, with file name as `op.xml` and **do not choose the first row as header option**. Also select quote character as `No quote character`. The following is how I configured the sink dataset.

[image]

- Now in mapping import schemas and keep only the above created additional column.

[image]

- This will create a file `op.xml` at the destination storage account. The contents of the file would be as shown below:

[image]

- Now you can use another copy data activity, choose XML as a the source file format and select the above generated `op.xml` file. When I preview the data, it is showing the data as expected.

[image]

Now, you can write this file to any required file format as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks for your description. One question, when using web acticity, is it possible to somehow use `Auth headers` just like in linked services when using REST ?

Comment: Hey @AlexK, yes, you can give the Auth header same as in the REST API while using web activity as well.

Comment: I'm managed to load a xml content into a csv file but it is a string. I tried to create a data set with xml but I am not able to select it as a sink source. Must be a bug or something

Comment: Copy data does not support XML as sink. That is the reason why I have loaded entire content as a string (which you managed to do) without quote character and then write it with file extension as `.xml` (even though selected sink is csv). Now read this file again using the copy data with XML dataset instead and then write it to necessary format (check the last 2 images for reference)

Comment: Hey @AlexK, has it worked? If not, try to provide the sink configuration of the above copy activity if the issue persists.

Comment: yes I just tried it now and it looks like it is working now

Comment: also please note web activity cannot process output reposne greater than 4mb